# Add a scope variable as a argument for window.open function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to add a scope variable as a argument for window.open function, i am using the following code.

```
onclick="window.open($scope.positionsURL, '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;"
```

I am getting the following error.

**Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined**

What am I missing? Do I have any syntax error? Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ng-click` instead:

```
ng-click="open(positionsURL, '_system', 'location=yes')"
```

And define the function `$scope.open` in the controller. Should be something like that:

```
$scope.open = function (url, name, spec) {
    $window.open(url, name, spec);  // don't forget to inject $window in the controller
    return false;
}
```